# Beginner: How to I access an external SMB server? Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, raspberry-pi, smb

I have a raspberry pi, with samba configured properly. It's IP address is xx.xx.xx.xx and the proper ports are forwarded. I can access it from my mac by doing `open smb://xx.xx.xx.xx` but I do not know how to do it from a Windows computer. I have tried `\\xx.xx.xx.xx\sharedfolder` in a browser and mapping network drive at `\\xx.xx.xx.xx\sharedfolder` which crashes my computer when using "Map network drive."

I know this is a really stupid question, but I have found no help through google searches, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If it crashes your whole computer, you have bigger issues

Answer (score 1):

You basically open the Start menu, search for **run**, click enter, and then type in this `\xx.xx.xx.xx`.